# Can we use tapply function in conjunction with ks.test in R?

Tags: r

Can we use tapply function in conjunction with ks.test in R ?

Tapply is used to apply functions on multiple results at a single time.

```
tapply(airquality$Month,airquality$Day, ks.test)
```

When I used the function I got the error like this:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Can anyone suggest is there a possibility of using tapply with ks.test?

Comment: y is an required argument of ks.test. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I tried using this too 

In this case I am using WorldPhones, which is a predefined dataset in R

    tapply(ks.test(WorldPhones[,4],WorldPhones[,2]))

Comment: what about `ks.test(airquality$Month,airquality$Day)`

Comment: That worked fine, I have tried it earlier. 

The thing is I wanted to apply ks.test simultaneously on both the results. See if you help me out, as I am new to r.

Answer (score 0):

As @HubertL mentioned, `ks.test` in `R` requires the y argument hence the error telling you 'y' is missing. From the documentation, y should be a numeric vector in the case of the two sample KS test. If you are performing a one sample ks test, y should be a string for the distribution you are comparing it to (e.g. pnorm for normal, p.gamma for gamma).

I think this is what you want:

```
tapply(airquality$Month, airquality$Day, ks.test, y = "pnorm")
```

`dplyr` solution (list columns)

```
airquality %>% group_by(Day) %>% do(test_result = ks.test(.$Month, y = "pnorm")
```

If you wanted to get a ks.test for both variables then you want:

```
lapply(airquality[c("Month", "Day")], ks.test, y = "pnorm")
```